# upgrade to angular 8 from 7 errors with incompatible peer dependency

Tags: angular, upgrade, angular8

ng update @angular/cli @angular/core . -  Getting the below error when upgrading from 7 to 8, following the guide from https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0

`````
> "@angular/core" (requires "^6.0.0" (extended), would install "8.0.0").```

Incompatible peer dependencies found. See above.

package.json has the below versions


"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.3",
    .....
    ````
`````

Comment: Looks like [`@ngrx/store`](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) does not yet have a released version that supports angular 8.

Answer (score 1):

I encounters the same issue, some github issue suggested to use `--force` command with `ng upgrade`:

```
ng updgrate --all --force
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates the problem is that your version of `@ngrx/store` is not compatible with Angular 8 yet. Currently there are only 3 beta releases of `@ngrx/store` that supports Angular 8:

```
8.0.0-beta.0
8.0.0-beta.1
8.0.0-beta.2
```

The latest ([8.0.0-beta.2)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngrx/store/v/8.0.0-beta.2) was published to NPM 15 days ago (15-05-2018). To install it run

```
npm install @ngrx/store@8.0.0-beta.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [`@ngrx/store`](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) does not yet have a released version that supports angular 8. You would have to use their latest beta version, `8.0.0-beta.2 (2019-05-15)`, if you wanted to upgrade or wait until they release version 8.